# Sharing view for nested state in ionic tabs and keeping ion-nav-bar back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app, I have a profile state which can be accessed from many places in the app. I have a tabbed app, and I'd like to be able to navigate to a shared state, the profile. My problem is showing the back button in the `ion-nav-bar` when in the profile state, which will return the user to the previous state. My [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrYRoR?editors=1011) demonstrates the issue. I would even be fine with having the tabs show on the profile page, but I really want to avoid duplicating states.

The [second codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoXqGE?editors=0011) achieves my goal, by adding more states and injecting the user into the profile controller via the resolve. As you will see, I have two profile states, tab.users.profile, and tab.friends.profile, and they are both doing the exact same thing.

This works, and I guess it isn't such a problem, but I'd really prefer to DRY things up. In my actual app, I'd have the same state repeated 6+ times, and everything just screams at me that it is wrong.

Does anyone know a more efficient way to achieve my goal?